# Could This LocalThread Overwrite Other Servlet Requests' Data?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, filter, thread-safety

I have the following request context class that is used to collect certain information for future processing in Servlet filter:

```
public class ApplicationRequestContext {
  private static final ThreadLocal<AppRequest> tl = new ThreadLocal<AppRequest>();

  public static void begin(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    tl.set(getAppRequest(httpRequest));
  }

  public static void finish() {
    tl.remove();
  }
}
```

`getAppRequest(httpRequest)` just returns an object. And in the Servlet filter...

```
public class ApplicationServletFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
  @Override

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
      ApplicationRequestContext.begin(httpRequest);
      /* other stuff */
      chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) { /* … */ }
    finally {
      ApplicationRequestContext.finish();
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know, could this setup have multiple incoming requests to  **possibly** overwrite each others' data (`getAppRequest(httpRequest)` object obviously is going to be unique)? Is this even thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember, each `Thread` has its own `ThreadLocal` -- actually, to be precise, its own [`ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l182) (I'm using OpenJDK as a sample).

When your `ThreadLocal`, named `tl`, calls on its [`set()` method](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#l199), it basically creates a new `ThreadLocalMap` and have `tl` as a reference as a key to [create a `ThreadLocalMap.Entry`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#l308).

Since each Servlet request uses a unique thread (either from a managed thread pool or spawning a new one, and the fact that no two Servlet threads process the same request), then `tl.set()` have that `ThreadLocal`'s newly created `ThreadLocalMap` as a reference to that Servlet `Thread`'s `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap`.

Now, when [`tl.get()` is called](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#l159), we simply get the Servlet `Thread`'s `ThreadLocalMap`, and do a [lookup with `ThreadLocalMap.getEntry()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#l413), to fetch the value we have put in, e.g. `getAppRequest(httpRequest)`.

The main point to remember here is, yes, you are using a single `ThreadLocal` object, named `tl`, but each `Thread`, in this case, a thread that the Servlet container uses to process each request, including its filter(s), is going to have its own `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap` with a [weak] reference of this `ThreadLocal` object as its key.

So, `t1` is just a key in a table of `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap.Entry` (`tl.ThreadLocalMap.Entry`) to fetch `Thread`'s `LocalThread.ThreadLocalMap` which is unique to that thread alone. Therefore, it is thread-safe, and those `begin()` and `finish()` calls are basically putting data in each `Thread`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's thread-safe. And, It could not overwrite each others' data.

Because,

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html